# How to start a terminal outside of the Deno App with Deno

Tags: subprocess, deno

This is what I have so far

```
export const start_app = async () => {
  const denoRunPromise = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["./main.bat"],
  });
    await denoRunPromise.status();
};
```

What I'm looking to do is have this kick off a script that runs independent of my Deno App, and doesn't conclude when my main app does. I've looked [here](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.1/examples/subprocess), and can't seem to find anything. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I've tried not awaiting the end, but it dies with the process. I've tried reading the documentation, but it looks to only create a sub-process.

Comment: This isn't possible yet (see my answer below). Do you have a specific concern about having the Deno process continue while waiting on the child process?

Answer (score 0):

> As of Deno version `1.29.1`:

Deno doesn't yet include the capability to spawn a detached child process. This feature request is being tracked on GitHub at the following issue:

[denoland/deno#5501 - Detached processes in deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5501)